# publish localhost site on windows 7 iis

Tags: iis-7, dns, localhost

I had enough from shared web hosting(sql server on shared web hosting is just a joke ,additionally last web hosting I use, has a restriction of 3 mints for session process!! and they not support sessionstate mode as sqlserver)

so I decided to publish my local website on windows 7 .

I have static IP and port 80 open,I can browse my site from other network using IP address

like :http://46.117.24.192/.

I also have register domain (http://examplesite.com)

I want to configure the dns of the domain to my IP address

in domain management  I have to put 2 Name Servers

Name Server 1 *

Name Server 2 *

What shall I put in those name servers in order to use domain name for browsing my site?

Thanks for any help

Baaroz

Comment: can you be more specific? I really don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an A record to the name servers that sets your domain name to the IP Address.  So you would create an A record, set the host to "*" (or www if you want to have www), and then the IP address 46.117.24.192.

Comment: I found this free service that manage all the name servers:http://freedns.afraid.org  .   and a guide here:http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/hostnameathome.html